# tabulator filter top rows after sorting

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I have searched all the documentation and existing questions, but I couldn't find this use case:

I have a table where i sort on column X and I then want to display only the top 3 rows.

unfortunately, I cannot find any why to achieve this, can anyone help?

thank you

lorenzo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently no ways to show top rows after sorting in tabulator, the comment from Michael provides the best option in case of a static context.

I ended up directly passing a cut table for each option i had from the backend

Answer (score 1):

for this, I have a visible:false column that has a data value of 0 or 1. And I have a filter on that column that hides rows with value = 1. If you want to hide rows, getRows() and set this field to 1, and apply all filters (this used to be setFilters(getFilters()), but I think he has since added an applyFilters() now). This should then hide the rows you dont want seen.

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for your suggestion. unfortunately the context the data is more dynamic than this simplified scenario. what i learned from you your comment was still that there was no other way to set the filtering other than precalculating in the backend a field to sort on. I ended up preferring to create a cut table of the top rows for each of the options i had. thanks a lot for your help